# Не получается конвертировать Long в String

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

Пытаюсь сохранить время таймера обратного отсчёта, чтобы при выходе из приложения и при открытии его, скажем, через 3 часа, таймер показывал время с учётом этих 3 прошедших часов.
Ошибка java.lang.classcastexception: java.lang.long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

```
Ошибка в этой строке: 
 chronometer.setText(save.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, deadline1));
```

Код, вернее его часть, необходимая для понимания сути проблемы:

```
long duration = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24);
long endOfTask = System.currentTimeMillis() + duration;

  void saveText () {
    
      TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
      SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();
      editor.putLong(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, endOfTask);
      editor.apply();
}
         void loadText () {
    
        TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Long deadline = endOfTask - System.currentTimeMillis();
        String deadline1 = Long.toString(deadline);
        chronometer.setText(save.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, deadline1));
    }
```

Comment: `getString` -> `getLong`?

Comment: Tы сохраняешь putLong, а пытаешься прочитать getString. Как-то определись )